# Weird crash report : Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #26

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

**Please help me regarding this crash report unable to identify why this happen. Its only happening to Lenovo phones, work well on all other phone.**

STACK_TRACE = java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.somenewapp/com.somenewapp.CategoryActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2560) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2626) at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5740) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:766) Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class at com.somenewapp.CategoryActivity.onCreate(CategoryActivity.java:30) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6543) at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113) at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2513) ... 9 more android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class at com.somenewapp.CategoryActivity.onCreate(CategoryActivity.java:30) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6543) at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113) at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2513) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2626) at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5740) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:766)

**This is my onCreate method.**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category); //this is line 30

}
```

**This is my activity_category.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/india_bg"
    tools:context="com.somenewapp.CategoryActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
        android:src="@color/transparent_green"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/large_marg"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/large_marg"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/large_marg"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/large_marg"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
      android:src="@drawable/india_1024"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/narr_marg"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
            android:src="@drawable/import_yarn_from_india_1024"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/narr_marg"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/narr_marg"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/narr_marg"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/narr_marg"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/narr_marg"
            android:background="@color/aluminum"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/narr_marg"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
      android:src="@drawable/indian_flag_1947"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/narr_marg"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
      android:src="@drawable/indian_flag"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/narr_marg"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/narr_marg"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/narr_marg"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/narr_marg"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/narr_marg"
            android:background="@color/aluminum"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/narr_marg"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
      android:src="@drawable/india_new_sec"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is an issue with Lenovo phones and not specific to the API version of the device you are testing on?

Comment: Yes, I am sure this is problem is not specific to API version, as I have tested on API level 17 to 25. Code works well.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the error is line 26 of the layout, which corresponds to this `ImageView`:

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
  android:src="@drawable/india_1024"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

My best bet will be that drawable `india_1024` has some kind of resource qualifier that makes it fail, or either is a huge image that makes this device fail because of an out-of-memory. Probably the former.

Could you add more information on this drawable?

Comment: india_1024 drawable has specs

resolution: 1024* 240
and its only 37kb

Comment: Do you have access to the device? If so, it will be a good idea to remove this ImageView to see if it's really the culprit. Take into account that the size of the compressed image is irrelevant, what matters is the uncompressed size of the image. Plus, you're using `adjustViewBounds="true"`, which means it could potentially expand (on API 17 or newer, which I think is your case).

Comment: Actually, I got a crash report and not able to recreate it on other devices. All works fine, even I have tracked it on android monitor not much memory usages. Any other suggestion please.

Comment: Anything that I suggest will be of no help without the device to verify it. Layout looks pretty normal, so what I said above are my only ideas on what may be causing the issue. I suggest you to find the exact model and try to get access to a unit, either by friends, family, buying it... or try to see if in an online device farm there is this model available: https://testobject.com/ https://kobiton.com/ https://aws.amazon.com/es/device-farm/ https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/